# Find an invertible matrix and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question.  I know what the answer is supposed to be (I put it in mathlab).  However, when I go through the individual steps I keep getting the wrong answer.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

[Here's the question with the correct answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oF5S.png)

The diagonal matrix D is fine, it's the P matrix that I am having issues with.  I'm getting 5 and 1 for the center column of the matrix.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There can be more than one correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&-20&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$, the eigenvalues associated to $A$ are $\lambda_1=3$ and $\lambda_2=-1$. Now, we can look for a eigenvector $\mathbf{v}=(x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0)$ associated to $\lambda_i$ by making
$$(A-\lambda_i Id)(\mathbf{v})=0.$$
For $i=1$ this yields $y=0$, so we are free to choose $x,\;z\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular, we can choose the eigenvectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Now, for $i=2$ it follows that $z=0$ and $x=5y$. We can then choose the vector $$(5100/5201,1020/5201,0),$$
since $1020*5=5100$. Then, the matrix P has its columns equal to the eigenvectors. Explicitly, we can make
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&5100/5201&0\\0&1020/5201&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: But if you take the middle column in $P$ and multiply that column by the scalar $\frac{5201}{1020}$, that middle column is certainly still an eigenvector, and you get the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&5&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ which the asker talks about.

Comment: Exactly! This is just the relation $x=5y$, which is absolutely important to correlate to the asker`s answer.